# Text being lost in transmit in chat client

Tags: java, sockets

I have a Java Client/Server chat application and after a connection gets established, only about 1 quarter of the data is being received by the recipient. What could the problem be? Here is a print screen of what happens exactly:
[image: Printscreen of Application]

Code for reading from socket:

```
public void somethingElse(){
    try {
           if(in.readLine() != null){
                messageBufferIn = in.readLine();
               System.out.println(in.readLine());
               chat.append(recipient + ": " + messageBufferIn + "\n");
           }
           } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }     
}
```

Code for thread that runs above method:

```
public class chatListener extends Thread{
static main main = new main();
//static Thread mainThread = new Thread(main);
public void run(){
    while(main.isConnected == true){
        main.somethingElse();
    }
}
```

}

The above thread gets run as soon as a connection gets established

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you call in.readLine, the scanner moves down to the next line; you can't keep calling it a few times, as it will skip the lines you never used essentially. Try this to replace somethingElse():

```
public void somethingElse(){
    try {
           String line;//Added a variable to store the current line to; readLine is 
           //dynamic, it returns the next line each call, so if we store to a variable,
           //we only call it once, and hold that value
           if((line = in.readLine()) != null){// (line = in.readLine()) != null is shorthand to store readLine to line, and then check if that returned value is null or not
               System.out.println(line);//Print out the line
               chat.append(recipient + ": " + line + "\n");//Append it
           }
     } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }     
}
```

Before, you were calling in.readLine once to check if it was null, then you saved the next line, then printed the next one. Hence the pattern of (fail success fail | fail success fail etc.) = Only messages 2 + 5 showing up

Comment: That worked wonderfully! I cant believe my mistake was so simple! Thanks for helping me understand my mistake also!

Comment: Yup! Glad to be able to help! :)